# How to typehint 2nd order decorators/ decorator factories (PEP-612 ParamSpec)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, mypy, python-3.10

I have the following:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


class GeneratorLen(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, gen: Iterator[T], length: int):
        self.gen = gen
        self.length = length

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.length

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return self.gen


def sized(
    length: int,
) -> Callable[Callable[P, Iterator[T]], Callable[P, IterableAndSized[T]]]:  # ERROR
    def _makesized(
        func: Callable[P, Iterator[T]],
    ) -> Callable[P, IterableAndSized[T]]:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> IterableAndSized[T]:
            return GeneratorLen(func(*args, **kwargs), length)

        return wrapper

    return _makesized
```

The `sized` decorator can be used to add a `__len__` attribute to an iterator to hint its length to functions like `len()`.

However mypy gives an error: [*TIO!*](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=ignore-missing-imports%2Cscripts-are-modules&gist=bf85fdc7a1b9179247025840a70d83f4)

> `main.py:37: error: The first argument to Callable must be a list of types or "..."`

Is this not implemented yet or am I doing something wrong? Using mypy latest (0.931)

Answer (score 4):

Close, was just missing a pair of brackets around the arg to Callable:

```
def sized(
    length: int,
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, Iterator[T]]], Callable[P, IterableAndSized[T]]]:
    ...
```

---

Perhaps a clearer minimum example:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import *

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def add_logging(name: str) -> Callable[[Callable[P, R]], Callable[P, R]] :
    def outer(func: Callable[P,R]) -> Callable[P,R]:
        def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print(f"Hello {name}: {result}")
            return result
        return inner
    return outer
    
@add_logging("world")
def foo(x:int, y: str) -> float:
    print(f"got {x=}, {y=}")
    return 1.0
    
    
reveal_type(foo)  # Revealed type is "def (x: builtins.int, y: builtins.str) -> builtins.float*"
```